# Is possible to install/update Gnome 3.20 via Snap in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: gnome, 16.04

Probably it is not possible right now because a lot of work have to be done in order to have the packages ready. But I [read](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/04/ubuntu-1604-lts-to-offer-updates-via.html) that it could be possible.

Anyone knows if there are plans to make Gnome available via Snap?

Edit: It seems that [Gnome Software Centre will support Snap](http://news.softpedia.com/news/gnome-software-3-22-will-support-installation-of-snaps-flatpak-repository-files-506580.shtml). But it does not mean that Gnome is going to be installed by Snap, yet.

Answer (score 0):

No. At least not yet.

It's also unclear whether Snap can be used for an entire desktop or is more for running individual apps. Once someone does the work, you could run a snap for gedit 3.20 or cheese 3.20. On the other hand, it may not be feasible for a snap to include gnome-shell 3.20 or even the 3.20 version of the Settings app (gnome-control-center) because they are lower-level system software.